# Test user input until conditions are met

Tags: python

In python, I need the input of a user to be between a range of years.

Using if statement returns the error (if he's out of range) to the user and invite him to make another choice of year.

The second time he chooses a year need to  be tested again with the same conditions. Which doesn't happen yet.

What would be the best solution to have his input tested all over again, until conditions are met ?

Here's some piece of the actual code

```
year = input("Enter a year between 1900 and 2099 : ")
if year >= "1900" or year <= "2099":
    year = (input("The year you entered is out of range, please try again : "))
year = int(year)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want conditions like `year >= "1900"`? This will do a string lexicographical comparison, as opposed to comparing if the year is less than 1900. For example, `'a' >= '1900'` evaluates to `True` because `a` has a larger ASCII value than `1`. Also, `'19000' >= '1900' or '19000' <= '2099'` will also evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation:

You can use a `while` loop. A `while` loop will run until a certain condition is `False`. In this case it will run until the `break` keyword is used, because the condition will always be `True`. You can also use `try` and `except` do make sure the input it an integer. And use `continue` to start the loop again if it is not an integer.

#### Code:

```py
prompt = "Enter a year between 1900 and 2099: "

while True:
    year = input(prompt)

    try:
        year = int(year)
    except ValueError:
        prompt = "The year you entered is out of range, please try again : "
        continue 

    if year >= 1900 or year <= 2099:
        break
    else:
        prompt = "The year you entered is out of range, please try again : "
```

Comment: should `year = int(year)` be exactly below the `year` assignment?

Comment: @zois Thanks for pointing it out, I'll fix that.

Comment: Actually you are checking for strings with the `if` statement, so it works as it is

Comment: @zois I'll probably make it integers.

Comment: Great, thanks for your input. Strings removed as well. My mistake, or habit.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the condition to while True should be defined ahead(above if you prefer) or not ?

Comment: @hyperswiss I think you didn't understand the code

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal I take it as a "no", and start to understand why. Thanks

Comment: Look at th Explanation section in the answer. If is answered your question, Yoo can accept the answer by clicking the check icon